# c++ bitstring to byte

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation, bitstring

For an assignment, I'm doing a compression/decompression of Huffman algorithm in Visual Studio. After I get the 8 bits (`10101010` for example) I want to convert it to a byte. This is the code I have:

```
    unsigned byte = 0;
    string stringof8 = "11100011";
    for (unsigned b = 0; b != 8; b++){
        if (b < stringof8.length())
            byte |= (stringof8[b] & 1) << b;
    }
    outf.put(byte);
```

First couple of bitstring are output correctly as a byte but then if I have more than 3 bytes being pushed I get the same byte multiple times. I'm not familiar with bit manipulation and was asking for someone to walk me through this or walk through a working function.

Comment: Why do you |= 1 << b if b is >= stringof8.length()?

Comment: What is `stringof8`?

Comment: Is your stringof8 a string of ascii characters representing the binary bits? If so, then ascii "1" is converted to numeric 1 by subtracting from it ascii "0" first, and then you can do bit manipulations.

Comment: Show us declaration of stringof8.

Comment: so example,  string stringof8 = "11100011" I want to output the byte it equals onto an output file

Comment: `stringof8[b]` gives you a character **which represents** either 0 or 1, not the actual values 0 or 1. You'll need `stringof8[b] - '0'` to get that.

Comment: @clcto @DNT actually, the given code works (the `& 1` properly masks out the desired value), but it is less readable

Comment: @DrewMcGowen no where does the standard say that the least significant bit of `'0'` has to be 0.

Comment: @clcto perhaps I should've added it works iff the compiler uses ASCII

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset Why no?

Comment: Thank you to everyone for their replies! All of the replies helped me to understand what I did wrong and what I needed to fix

Comment: @Tacet the link was extremely helpful! ty

Comment: @AB_ thank you for the code! Was able to correctly output bytes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using std::bitset

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <bitset>


int main() {

    std::string bit_string = "10101010";
    std::bitset<8> b(bit_string);       // [1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0]
    unsigned char c = ( b.to_ulong() & 0xFF);
    std::cout << static_cast<int>(c); // prints 170

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @AB_ thank you for the code! Was able to correctly output bytes

Comment: @AB_ i was wondering. Once you output the bytes on the file using the bitset can you read in the unsigned long byte and reconvert to a string? I was trying to play with converting back and forth but was unable to get correct bitstr or even the first 8 bit string using std::bitset

Comment: read from file as string and call std::bitset<8> b(bit_string);, call b.to_ulong()