# reading in ascii characters from a file and then turning them into a bit string c++

Tags: c++, ifstream

So i have ascii characters ãÅT on a file and I was trying to convert them back to a binary string (so the binary strings it should give back are (respectively): "11100011", "11000101", "01010100"). How would you read in unsigned char (bytes) and then convert them to a bitstring? Any detailed tutorial links and/or advice would help! Thank you!

---edit -----

so here is some code I'm playing with that gets the characters I was mentioning (part of a question I asked on [c++ bitstring to byte](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26656878/c-bitstring-to-byte)).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <bitset>
#include <vector>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;

void main(){
    ofstream outf;
    outf.open("test.outf", std::ofstream::binary);
    ifstream inf;

    //given string of 1's and 0's, broke them down into substr
    //of 8 and then used a bitset to convert them to a byte
    //character on the output file
    string bitstring = "11100011110001010101010";
    unsigned char byte = 0;
    cout << bitstring.length() << endl;
    for (int i = 0 ; i < bitstring.length(); i += 8){
        string stringof8 = "";
        if (i + 8 < bitstring.length()){
            stringof8 = bitstring.substr(i, 8);
            cout << stringof8 << endl;
        }
        else
            stringof8 = bitstring.substr(i);

        if (stringof8.size() < 8){
            stringof8 += "0";
            cout << stringof8 << endl;
        }

        bitset<8> b(stringof8);
        byte = (b.to_ulong()&0xFF);
        outf.put(byte);
    }
    cout << endl;

    system("pause");
}
```

i tried to get the bitstring back. When I look at the binary mode of notepad++ , it shows the same binary strings (if i broke them up into 8 pieces).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert it bit by bit. Another approach is converting decimal number to binary number.
Updated:

```
string convert(unsigned char c){
    string bitstr(8,'0');
    int n = 7;
    while(n >= 0){
        bitstr[7-n] = (c >> n) & 1 ? '1' : '0';
        --n;
    }
    return bitstr;
}

string convert10To2(unsigned char c){
    string bitstr = "";
    int val = c;
    int base = 128;
    int n = 8;
    while(n-- > 0){
        bitstr.append(1, (val/base + '0'));
        val %= base;
        base /= 2;
    }
    return bitstr;
}

int main() {
    ofstream out;
    out.open("data.txt");
    char ccc = (char)227;
    out << ccc;
    out.close();
    ifstream in;
    in.open("data.txt");
    int ival = in.get();
    char c = ival;
    cout<<convert(c)<<endl; //output: 11100011
    cout<<convert10To2(c)<<endl; //output: 11100011
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: first off, thank you for your reply! With this I was able to get 'T' correctly has you demonstrated here but for the 'ã', 'Å' it gave incorrect binary string. Is this because the 'ã', 'Å' are extended ascii?

Comment: Sorry, my function has a bug previous. Now fixed, and you need to use 'unsigned char' as parameter type. I think the main problem for you is how to write and read the extended character. My function works find as long as the correct unsigned char parameter is passed in.

Comment: And the data.txt displays a single 'ã' correctly when I open it with Sublime text in Mac OS.

Comment: thank you x2!!! as you said you said, as long as the correct unsigned char is passed in I was able to get the correct bitstring. Turns out I was reading in wrong. So going to work with that and edit and clean up my program.

Answer (score 0):

Just store the characters in an a character array and use the bitset function like so.

```
#include <bitset>

char bbb[3] = {'b', 'f', 't'};
for (std::size_t i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
  {
      cout << bitset<8>(bbb[i]) << endl;
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you for your reply! I will try that and see if it works with my problem